# rack session resets/expires

Tags: ruby, session, webserver, sinatra, rack

Currently I am using enable :sessions for my sinatra webserver. But I need to move into a memory based session management

When I use Rack::Session::Pool, it runs although my session seems to expire on page reload, or even on a new Ajax Call being made.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Passenger or one of the other webservers, it's because a new thread gets created.  If you reload on your page quickly you'll probably get expired sessions with a new thread being created (it's in memory on a specific webserver thread)

If you reload your page slowly it shouldn't expire the session because your still on the same webserver thread.

Comment: Ah I see. The issue for me is that my app is highly ajaxed, hence I'll have calls running simultaneously. 
Is there a way, I can manage this ?

Comment: You can use Rack::Session:Cookie or Rack::Session:Memcache, I haven't tested those out yet fully (I'm having trouble implementing them for some reason) - or use a database table for the session store

Comment: Prakash, please go here to see my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175854/rack-session-cookie-and-sinatra-setting-and-accessing-data

Answer (score 2):

Nick is correct about the threading issue that Passenger brings to light.

Redis is a great in-memory solution. It is incredibly lightweight. You can find out more here: http://redis.io/.

I use the Redis adapter for `Rack::Session`.

You can find more about it here: http://redis-store.org/redis-rack/

It is pretty easy. Just include `gem redis-rack` in your Gemfile and do this in your sinatra app

```
require 'redis-rack'
disable :sessions
use Rack::Session::Redis
```