# Rack Session Cookie and Sinatra - setting and accessing data

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra, rack, session-cookies

I was using Rack Session Pool, however my users would get kicked off one webserver thread onto another making the session data expire.  I started toying around with just enable :sessions in Sinatra, however I am unable to use that because I have mutliple apps using Sinatra (same key it appears to be using - not sure if this is because its the same host or not)

So since my apps would break each other, I now am trying Rack Session Cookie and setting the variables (same thing as enable :sessions, but you can set the variables)

Great so that works!  But now I cannot access the session data the way I was using it, in Rack Session Pool and in enable: sessions

```
session[:user] = nick
puts session[:user]
```

you get the idea...

Question is why can I access session data with session[:user] in Pool and Sinatra enable :sessions, but not in Rack Session Cookie?  Am I missing anything? All I am doing is below

config.ru

```
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'key',
                             :domain => "localhost",
                             :path => '/',
                             :expire_after => 14400, # In seconds
                             :secret => 'secret'
```

EDIT:

Did some more testing and found that it's actually putting it in the session variable, however as soon as it moves to a new method or redirection the session variable appears to be dropped (is this cookie really larger than 4KBs?!) - it can't be because enable :sessions works just fine

Comment: Just dump request.cookies for every request and see if you can find anything suspicious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix this problem:

```
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'my_app_key',
                             :path => '/',
                             :expire_after => 14400, # In seconds
                             :secret => 'secret_stuff'
```

Do you see the difference from the above? - No Domain, if I let Rack::Session::Cookie specify the domain or the browser (whoever does it), I have no errors between mutliple Sinatra/Rack apps...

Comment: Isn't this approche very insecure?

Comment: If its just a cookie with no actual authentication/authorization data in it then no, your just setting sessions and putting some data in it

Comment: I have the same problem and tried your solution verbatim.  But now, no matter what I put into the `session` hash, `before do; p session ; end` shows only `{"session_id"=>"b59..."}`.

Comment: That is strange, what version of sinatra and rack?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with the domain 'localhost'.  This thread describes in more details as to why having localhost as the domain wouldn't work: [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)

A fix would be to setup a domain in your hosts file like

```
127.0.0.1    superduper.dev
```

Then set your domain in your sessions settings to superduper.dev.  Then during development you can go to whatever port you might need.  Ex. superduper.dev:5000